# call javascript method from mvc3 controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a button on the cshtml view..its clicked every-time an item is scanned.
The user has to do it one by one and once all the items have been scanned..i want to opem/pop up a new window plus redirect him to another page.. The condition whether it was the last item..is being checked in the controller method.
How can i call a javascript to open the new window from the controller..right before my 'redirecttoaction' ?

is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample pattern:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    // TODO Process the scanned code model.Code

    if (IsLastItem())
    {
        model.IsLast = true;
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and inside the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Code)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
@if (Model.IsLast)
{
    <text>
    window.open('@Url.Action("foo")', 'foo');
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("bar")';
    </text>
}
</script>
```

Comment: darin..  this is how it is now..                        

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    // TODO Process the scanned code model.Code

    if (IsLastItem())
    {
        model.IsLast = true; 
        return redirecttoaction("another page");
    }
    return View(model);
}

As you see, it doesnt post back to the view..but is redirecting to another page..

So basically..i want a pop-up plus redirection..

And so what I am trying is .. call the pop-up right before the redirecttoaction.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clean to call JavaScript from controller. Instead, move the logic of checking if its a last item to the client side and call appropriate controller action as appropriate.

Comment: mahesh..this will be a javascript window. regardless where the decision is being made..controller action has to call javascript window.open

Comment: Then, why not open that window with destination as the redirect action after you check the logic of if its the last element?

Comment: there are two actions reqd based on the decision from page-A..  1. open this pop-up  2. redirect to page B or C. I considered putting this pop-up javascript in the document.ready of subsequent page. But sometimes subsequent page is B..sometimes C thru B.. sometimes directly to C.  So.. thats not a solution either

Comment: @jeff: I think, you should put the logic that is required to determine which page to got to, from Page X in itself. So that you don't have to worry about it, you just load that page and it knows where to go from there, as an independent entity.